# Show timestamps using user-specified timezone

Tags: php, laravel, timezone, config

In my app, there is a `timezone` column for each user in the database. This represents their own selected PHP timezone e.g. `America/Toronto`.

My issue is that I want all timestamps displayed in the app to reflect the user-selected timezone. What is the simplest way of doing this? I tried modifying the `App\Http\Controller` controller class with this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    config(['app.timezone' => Auth::user()->timezone]);
}
```

But this throws a `Trying to get property of non-object` error.

Comment: Might be better to this kind of stuff in JavaScript.

Comment: Not really, what if the user flew to meet clients but wants to see data in the timezone they selected at home? I'd much rather have this user-specified.

Comment: Alright then, might be better to pull from here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro

Comment: This needs to work in an offline context so I'd rather the timezone be set by the column value in the `users` table. Thank you for your comments, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with one project I've worked on and, while *I think* there is not definite and absolute good answer to this question, I offer what I decided to go with myself.

First thing to know: depending on you usage, changing the value of `app.timezone` *could* be problematic, because this would ot only have changed how the date and time are presented to the user, but also how it is saved to the database (for example, every timestamps (ie: `created_at`) of that user would be in the user's timezone while those are usually consistent within the app).

In the end I've simply used accessors on my models! With a `someField` attribute that is bound to a date time object:

```
public function getSomeFieldAttribute($value)
    {
        return is_null($value) ? null : Carbon::parse($value, $this->timezone());
    }
```

Now in your case, there is some caveat:

- You wouldn't be able to use (I think?) the `auth` facade in your model, but you probably could make a relationship to make it easier to get. I myself used a cached value for the timezone attribute and fetch it from there.
- You would have to either repeat with all your models, but you could also make a trait to make it easier and less repeaty.

Comment: All timestamps are inserted using `UTC` regardless of the user timezone.

Comment: Looks like mutators are the way to go, though.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that related to my answer? That would still not be true if you changed the value of `app.timezone`. This is the value used by Laravel to work with timezone.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see what you meant. Yeah, a mix of mutator and accessor would be great on that.

Comment: @kjdion84 that being said, you probably don't _need_ to save as user's timezone. I think it's good to have everything saved to database as UTC and converted to user's timezone on the fly when you need to display it.